# cancelling subscription via stripe-node in nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

I am using stripe-node library for integrating the Stripe payment gateway.

Here is my lambda function to cancel the subscription.

```
let stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_....');


function handler(event, context) {
    const subId = event.params.subscriptionId;
    stripe.subscriptions.del(
        subId, 
        (err, confirmation) => {
            if (err) {
                return context.fail(err);
            }
        }
    );
}

exports.handler = handler;
```

I am getting this stack trace error in cloud watch.

```
Error   
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "An error occurred with our connection to Stripe.",
    "type": "StripeConnectionError",
    "raw": {
        "message": "An error occurred with our connection to Stripe.",
        "detail": {
            "errorType": "Error",
            "errorMessage": "write ETIMEDOUT",
            "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
            "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
            "syscall": "write",
            "stack": [
                "Error: write ETIMEDOUT",
                "    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:92:16)",
                "    at writevGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:132:26)",
                "    at TLSSocket.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:782:11)",
                "    at TLSSocket.Socket._writev (net.js:791:8)",
                "    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:401:12)",
                "    at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:519:5)",
                "    at TLSSocket.Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:338:7)",
                "    at ClientRequest.end (_http_outgoing.js:782:17)",
                "    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:491:15)",
                "    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:26)"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to cancel the subscription via CURL as suggested in docs, It worked fine.

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/sub_49ty4767H11z6a \
  -u sk_test_4.......: \
  -X DELETE
```

Comment: Might be an SSL issue, or it might be a problem with the connecting. The cURL succeeding is promising. Are you running the cURL command on the same host that you're running stripe-node on? You can also try running https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability

Comment: I have done cUrl by my local system. This is the lambda functiions code snippets. So I have n't checked there [taintedzodiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100328/taintedzodiac).

Comment: Definitely sounds like a connectivity issue from lambda to Stripe's servers, then. That is the error you'd see in that situation.